# How to align image next to text with display:flex (responsive)

Tags: responsive-design, alignment

I would like to place an image next to accordion however i dont know if I should set a value for width with vh or pixel.

Second problem is; I use "display:flex", the image appears normal next to accordion however when I minimize it doesnt move to below accordion. Can you please tell me where I do wrong?

HTML

```
<section id="section4">
    <div class="tabs">
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabone" checked="checked">
        <label for="tabone">Tab 1</label>
        <div class="tab">
            <h1>Tab 1</h1>
        </div>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabtwo">
        <label for="tabtwo">Tab2</label>
        <div class="tab">
            <h1>Tab 2 </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid"></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#section4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 30px;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80vh;
}

.tabs label {
  order: 1;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin-right: 0.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background ease 0.2s;
}

.tabs .tab {
  order: 99;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: #ef4836;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .tab {
  display: block;
}

.grid {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg") no-repeat
    center center;
  width: 70vh;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  #section4 {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your image is a CSS div with a background you need to set the `height` of the div or it will not show. When it is beside the other element it's height is calculated by the height of the sibling, but when it gets moved below it no longer knows it's height so it disappears!

```
.grid {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg") no-repeat
    center center;
  width: 70vh;
  height: 100px; // <-- set height of the div to some value
}
```

Comment: but i dont want that it dissapers, i want o have it under accordion

Comment: your code currently puts it under the accordion... it's just a div with no height!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to allow you image or the div its in to grow or shrink with

```
flex-grow: 1;
```

in your css file.